# Select only one element .wrapper or .test

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Pls help, how i can select only one element `.wrapper` or `.test`

https://jsfiddle.net/nLg96ywe/

[image]

I want:

[image]
[image]

Thank you very much !

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What do you want to do?

Comment: i updated check pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use jquery method `.stopPropagation()` and replace `mouseenter` with `mouseover`, `mouseleave` with `mouseout`

```js
var ids = ['test','wrapper'];


$.each(ids, function(index, value) {

$('.' + value)
  .mouseover(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
 $(this).css('-webkit-box-shadow', 'inset 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(255,248,41,1)');
 $(this).css('-moz-box-shadow', 'inset 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(255,248,41,1)');
 $(this).css('box-shadow', 'inset 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(255,248,41,1)');
 $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
 $(this).css('-webkit-box-shadow', '');
 $(this).css('-moz-box-shadow', '');
 $(this).css('box-shadow', '');
 $(this).css('cursor','default');
  });
  
  });
```

```css
.wrapper
{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:#888;
  padding:50px;
}
.test
{
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="test">
test
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.stopPropagation` is not a jQuery function, it's javascript function. Right?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir maybe, here is a link https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/